# Jersey - Maven - MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json

Tags: json, web-services, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Currently i have the problem that everything in Netbeans my webservice works but if i start the jar file with the command "java -jar FILENAME PARAMETERS there is the following error.

**MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type
=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List**

I need an expert do solve this problem :/. It is very strange because when i execute the jar in Netbeans it works.

**pom.xml**

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>at.schneider.development</groupId>
<artifactId>PhotoBoothImageService</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>PhotoBoothImageService</name>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
        <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
        <version>[0.4, 0.5)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                            <mainClass>at.schneider.development.photoboothimageservice.Main</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.26-b02</jersey.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>
```

**Function:**

```
@GET
@Path("/getimages")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Image> getImages() {
    availableImages = getImageListFromDirectory(Paths.get(configuration.getProperties().get(BASE_DIR).toString()));
    return availableImages;
}
```

Thanks in advice!

Best Regards

Comment: What is `Image` like?

Comment: With MOXy, wrap your `List<Image>` into a class and return it. Or change the JSON provider to Jackson.

Comment: Make sure `Image` is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. This is required with MOXy, as it uses JAXB under the hood

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin i attached my image Class

Comment: Ok i found the solution:

jersey-media-json-jackson has to be the first dependency :) .. wtf ..

**EDITED in the question**

Comment: same problem here. moving dependency on top worked. BUT WHY???

Comment: Indeed this is the solution, why not reply yourself and note that this solved it?

Comment: @besil Maybe the project has dependency on the same jar but with different version and somehow the dependencies got mixed and the system was unable to locate the correct class.

Comment: idem, it works at the top. I compared all transitive dependency versions... all the same!

Comment: ok, I added an answer about the *why*'s and a link to a way to fix it

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552733/jersey-maven-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json/52291171#comment76119865_44552733) by [Supercop89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7508271/supercop89):

> jersey-media-json-jackson has to be the first dependency.

Comment: This just saved my sanity!

Comment: And this is also the case with jersey-media-moxy

Answer (score 2):

Because `maven-assembly-plugin` squashes META-INF/services files, it seems the JacksonAutoDiscoverable SPI is gone.

By putting the dependency `jersey-media-json-jackson` at the top, it ends-up in a better state.

Here is a diff:

**JSON FEATURES NOT WORKING**

`META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeatureAutoDiscoverable`

```
org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeatureAutoDiscoverable
```

**JSON FEATURES WORKING**

`META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeatureAutoDiscoverable`:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.JacksonAutoDiscoverable
```

So, putting the dependency at the top will make Json features work, at the expense of some other stuff that you (maybe) don't need.

There are some ways to merge the services in maven-assembly-plugin: [Merging META-INF/services files with Maven Assembly plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310215/merging-meta-inf-services-files-with-maven-assembly-plugin)

See also: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-container-descriptor-handlers.html

EDIT: I played a lot with maven-assembly-plugin as described in the links, but wasn't able to make that work. Eventually, I switched to `maven-shade-plugin` and it worked on my first try. It also displays information on what it does:

```
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.28 in the shaded jar.
```

If maven-assembly-plugin had done so, I wouldn't have to search for the problem for 1 hour. Also, it didn't need a bunch of xml. Personal conclusion: much easier with the latter.