# Could not resolve substitution to value :$akka.stream-blocking io dispatcher

Tags: java, maven, akka, maven-assembly-plugin

I am new to akka,kindly help me with this.
On running the executable jar, I get the error:Could not resolve substitution to value :$akka.stream-blocking io dispatcher

[This is my reference.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIahS.png)

[This is the error on running executable jar created after mvn assembly:single](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAnLx.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [reference.conf and your application.conf are merged](https://github.com/lightbend/config#note-about-resolving-substitutions-in-referenceconf-and-applicationconf), and to facilitate this, you need to tell maven to append the `reference.conf` so that all of it's substitutions are resolved.

If you're using maven-shade-plugin, then your [POM should be configured like so](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/21120) such that `reference.conf` is being appended by the `AppendingTransformer`:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>

                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                </transformer>

              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

If you're using maven-assembly-plugin, then [see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689041/1080804).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your assembly merges the various `reference.conf` together rather than keeping only one.

As a side note, do not put your own configurations in `reference.conf`, use `application.conf` instead as described [here](https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior).

Comment: Can you guide me how to merge reference.conf together