# Service Loader not finding any implementations when packaged as a jar

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have a JavaFx project running on Java 10 that runs perfectly in IntelliJ, which, to me, means that I am packaging the multi-module project incorrectly. I have attempted to search for fixes but I haven't found any.

> Problem

I "successfully" create a .jar, as in I get no errors from the maven package, but when I right click on it and run, my program crashes because it doesn't find the services and thus can't continue with normal operation.

> Example

The code below will output `IMPLEMENTATIONS` when run via IntelliJ, but `NO IMPLEMENTATIONS` when run via my .jar

```
ServiceLoader<Db> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Db.class);
if(!loader.iterator().hasNext()){
    log.error("NO IMPLEMENTATIONS");
}else {
    for(Db db : loader){
        log.error("IMPLEMENTATIONS");
    }
}
```

> top pom.xml build section

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=gson</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED,program</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=controlsfx</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.1</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dlog4j.debug</argLine>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Db module pom.xml build section

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.1.1</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Main Project pom.xml build section

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>startup.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>startup.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>program</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am really unsure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that entries in META-INF/services/ are lost - that needs a handler for the assembly plugin, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47310215/21499) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689041/21499). Perhaps the assembly plugin is too old?

Answer (score 0):

Is your code modular or not? If it is, then you also have to declare your services and their usage in your module-info.java file. If your packaged jars actually contain the required files and declarations can be easily checked by unpacking and expecting them.