# ERROR org.nd4j.linalg.compression.BasicNDArrayCompressor - Error loading ND4J Compressors via service loader

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j

Trying to run DL4J using NVIDIA cuDNN library (Windows10):

https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/multi-project/explanation/configuration/backends/cudnn

In my pom I added:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <dl4j-master.version>1.0.0-M2.1</dl4j-master.version>
        <nd4j.backend>nd4j-cuda-11.6</nd4j.backend>
        <jcommon.version>1.0.24</jcommon.version>
        <jfreechart.version>1.0.13</jfreechart.version>
        <javacv.version>1.5.5</javacv.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.6</logback.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>${nd4j.backend}</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>${nd4j.backend}</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
            <classifier>windows-x86_64-cudnn</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/cuda-platform-redist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>cuda-platform-redist</artifactId>
            <version>11.6-8.3-1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-api</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

I create uber-jar:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.somename.Launcher</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After running jar, I got the error:
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading ND4J Compressors via service loader: No compressors were found. This usually occurs when running ND4J UI from an uber-jar, which was built incorrectly (without services resource files being included)**

```
10:39:06.143 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend - Loaded [JCublasBackend] backend
10:39:15.316 [main] INFO org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder - Number of threads used for linear algebra: 32
10:39:15.363 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.executioner.DefaultOpExecutioner - Backend used: [CUDA]; OS: [Windows Server 2019]
10:39:15.363 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.executioner.DefaultOpExecutioner - Cores: [8]; Memory: [4,0GB];
10:39:15.364 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.executioner.DefaultOpExecutioner - Blas vendor: [CUBLAS]
10:39:15.390 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasBackend - ND4J CUDA build version: 11.6.55
10:39:15.391 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasBackend - CUDA device 0: [Tesla T4]; cc: [7.5]; Total memory: [16105865216]
10:39:15.391 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasBackend - Backend build information:
 MSVC: 192930146
STD version: 201402L
DEFAULT_ENGINE: samediff::ENGINE_CUDA
HAVE_FLATBUFFERS
HAVE_CUDNN
10:39:32.606 [main] ERROR org.nd4j.linalg.compression.BasicNDArrayCompressor - Error loading ND4J Compressors via service loader: No compressors were found. This usually occurs when running ND4J UI from an uber-jar, which was built incorrectly (without services resource files being included)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.getCompressor(Nd4j.java:5288)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.getDouble(BaseNDArray.java:1785)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.getInt(BaseNDArray.java:1753)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.convertWritablesBatched(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:413)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.convertFeaturesOrLabels(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:353)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.nextMultiDataSet(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:326)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:206)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:346)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:421)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:53)
        at com.packagename.service.FAClassifierLearning.main(FAClassifierLearning.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading ND4J Compressors via service loader: No compressors were found. This usually occurs when running ND4J UI from an uber-jar, which was built incorrectly (without services resource files being included)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.compression.BasicNDArrayCompressor.loadCompressors(BasicNDArrayCompressor.java:66)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.compression.BasicNDArrayCompressor.<init>(BasicNDArrayCompressor.java:46)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.compression.BasicNDArrayCompressor.<clinit>(BasicNDArrayCompressor.java:39)
        ... 11 more
```

What did I miss?
How can these compressors be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try using the maven-shade-plugin as an alternative?

Shade would look like this:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>

        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer" />
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

If you want to continue using assembly, =look in the jar you'll find that certain resources are missing. Every backend has properties files: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/tree/master/nd4j/nd4j-backends/nd4j-backend-impls/nd4j-cuda/src/main/resources

META-INF/resources files are needed as well.

You'll see those here including the relevant compressor file:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/tree/74ca3775d9a01dfcd1b1058e36e33e3c1fbfa93a/nd4j/nd4j-backends/nd4j-backend-impls/nd4j-cuda/src/main/resources/META-INF/services

Your assembly declaration appears to miss some files.

We mainly use uber jar not assembly in our day to day but I found  another stack overflow post here:
[Merging META-INF/services files with Maven Assembly plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310215/merging-meta-inf-services-files-with-maven-assembly-plugin)

Either way please confirm if your zip file is missing these files and ensure they're added.

Comment: If this is the correct answer for you could you mark it as such? Thanks!